# Trying to create a list within a list

Tags: python

This is my code

```
Apple = ['Aapl', 300]
Microsoft = ['Msft', 180]

#List of Stocks in the Index
stocks = [Apple, Microsoft]

#Company Lookup to Find Ticker Symbol or Share Price
def lookup(stock):
    return stock
    n=0
    if stock == stocks[n]:
        stock = stock
    else: 
        n=n+1

stock = (input("What company would you like to look up?"))
lookup(stock)
print(stock)

##Non working

select = input("Would you like their ticker (1) or price (2)?") 
if select == 1:
    print(stock[0])
else:
    print(stock[1])
```

Currently what I'm getting is the 1st or 2nd letter in stock I.e. A or P for Apple, M or I for Microsoft.
I want Python to recognize that the value of the variable "stock" is actually and index and account for the 0 or 1 position in the index.  Any help?

Comment: You're passing the string `stock` into your function and immediately returning it. So `lookup()` returns a string not a list.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might be after is something like this:

```
Apple = ['Aapl', 300]
Microsoft = ['Msft', 180]

#List of Stocks in the Index
stocks = {'Apple': Apple, 'Microsoft': Microsoft}

#Company Lookup to Find Ticker Symbol or Share Price
def lookup(stock_input):
  if stock_input in stocks:
    return stocks[stock_input]
  else:
    print('{0} not found in {1}'.format(stock_input, stocks.keys()))

stock_input = input("What company would you like to look up?")
stock = lookup(stock_input)
print(stock)

select = int(input("Would you like their ticker (1) or price (2)?"))
if select == 1:
    print(stock[0])
else:
    print(stock[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.  As pointed out, the `lookup` function returns the string `"Aapl"` or `"Msft"`, rather than the list.  Then, the value of any `input` statement is a *string*, but your condition is comparing it to an *int*, so it'll always return `False`.  Therefore, it'll always print the second element of the `stock` string, which is either `a` or `s`.

To fix this, you could do this:

```py
def lookup(stock):
    for stock_i in stocks:
        if stock == stock_i[0]:
            retstock = stock_i
    return(retstock)
stock = (input("What company would you like to look up?")) 
stock = lookup(stock) 
print(stock[1]) 
select = input("Would you like their ticker (1) or price (2)?") 
if select == "1":
    print(stock[0])
elif select == "2":
    print(stock[1])
```